# Trigger to update parentId from cloned account

Tags: apex, trigger, clone, child-to-parent

I am building my first account trigger which will clone the triggering record. On the cloned account I will update a field on it called 'Master Record' and set it to true.  I also need to set the triggering record's `parentId` to the cloned account. Below is my code.

```apex
public with sharing class AccountTriggerHandler {
    public static void beforeInsertAction(List<Account> accountsToInsert) {
        Id profileId=userinfo.getProfileId();
        String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:profileId].Name;
        if(profileName == 'System Administrator') {
            if(CheckRecursive.runOnce()) {
                List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
                for (Account record : accountsToInsert) {
                    Account newAccount = record.clone(false, false, false, false);
                    newAccount.golden_record__c = true;
                    accountList.add(newAccount);
                    record.ParentId = record.Id; //doesn't exist yet
                }
                if(accountList.size()>0){
                    insert accountList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unable to figure out how to assign the cloned record's ID as the `parentId` on the triggering record since it doesn't exist yet.  I'm thinking I'm going to have to SOQL and build a map to connect each triggering record with the inserted cloned IDs or potentially make this an after trigger.

Comment: Have you looked at the `clone()` method in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Move the logic to an after trigger. In an after trigger, the record will have an Id.

Comment: Unfortunately when I do this the triggering account's fields aren't still in memory. So when I clone it, I'd have to define every single field again (or use a field set), which I don't want to use as I have way too many fields.